# Find Sum for Equation

Tags: summation

In my task, I've some questions to solve but I am stuck with the following one.

> **Question:** Find the following sum: $\frac{1}{22–1} + \frac{1}{42 –1} + \frac{1}{62 –1} + \dots + \frac{1}{202–1}.$

I tried to find many patterns but couldn't get one to solve it. Like I know the difference is $20$ in each, but there is not any way to find square and make combination, so I am totally stuck with it.

Can anyone guide me with this??

Comment: Where does this question come from, please? What's the context?

Comment: [Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+from+n%3D1+to+10+%281%2F%2820*n%2B1%29%29) finds 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{10} \frac{1}{20n+1}=\frac{32423431590702190}{227186523709446609}$$

Comment: @K.defaoite provided answer does not match with yours..

Comment: @Null Pointer Could you show us the provided solution then please?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know...I just googled it and every other link says it's answer is 10/21. (In MCQs portion) no one provided details that's why I am more confused.

Comment: By elementary considerations, the denominator must be divisible by $41$, so the sum can't possibly be $10/21$. Either you have stated the problem incorrectly, or everyone who says it's $10/21$ is wrong. So let me repeat my question: where does it come from? What is the context? And let me add, what are these links where it says $10/21$?

Comment: Is there any chance that the sum is really $${1\over2^2-1}+{1\over4^2-1}+\cdots+{1\over20^2-1}$$

Comment: Nope... @GerryMyerson

Comment: I don't know what you want, Null. You say the answer to your question is $10/21$, but several of us have told you that it can't possibly be $10/21$. You refuse to say anything about where the problem came from, or where these alleged links are that say it's $10/21$. What are you expecting to get out of this? The one thing you won't see is a proof that the numbers, the way you have written them, add up to $10/21$, because they don't. So, what do you want?

Comment: Is this where you saw it? https://www.meritnation.com/ask-answer/question/solve-this-q-33-what-is-the-value-of-the-following-exp/real-numbers/12558265 or this? https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-value-of-following-expression-dfrac1-2-2-1-+-dfrac1-4-2-1-+-dfrac1-6-2-1-+-cdots-dfrac1-20-2-1 or this? https://www.toppr.com/ask/question/what-is-the-value-of-the-following-expressionleft-dfrac122-1-right-left

Comment: @GerryMyerson No, not these...I was wrong, 10/21 is not the answer, sorry for confusions and thank you for help.

Comment: OK. Now: please, please, please where did the problem come from?

Comment: Actually I got an assignment from university, where this was one the many questions.

Comment: So, you've been cheating on your homework, Null?

Comment: Cheating or taking guidance (whatever name it) ..because I was totally stuck on it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get an *approximation*, write
$$S_n=\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{20 k+21}=\frac 1 {20}\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{ k+\frac{21}{20}}\sim \frac 1 {20}\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{ k+1}=\frac 1 {20}H_{n+1}$$ For $n=9$, this would give
$$S_{9}=\frac 1 {20}\times\frac{7381}{2520}=\frac{7381}{50400}\approx 0.146448$$  instead of
$$S_{9}=\frac{32423431590702190}{227186523709446609}\approx 0.142717$$

Comment: @Tortar. Thanks for the edit ! Cheers :-)

Comment: but given correct answer is 10/21. (0.476) but it gives 0.1427.

Comment: @NullPointer. It is not ! The correct answer is the monster given twice to you.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $${2\over n^2-1}={1\over n-1}-{1\over n+1}$$ So $${2\over2^2-1}+{2\over4^2-1}+\cdots+{2\over20^2-1}=1-{1\over3}+{1\over3}-{1\over5}+\cdots+{1\over19}-{1\over21}=1-{1\over21}={20\over21}$$ and we're done (if I've correctly guessed what question OP meant to ask).

Comment: good interpretation skills ahah

Comment: but this is not my question...